# Populate html table onload from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was following an example source code I found for populating a html table from javascript. 
However there is a disconnect in my knowledge. The javascript is inside a populateTable function to find an element and create the other elements for the table and populate it from an array.

I don't want this to be done from a button click but when the screen loads.

So lets say...

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<p>List of products below:</p>
<table> <--- how do I tell this table to be populated from my populateTable function
</table>
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

EDIT: -  I'm clearly learning javascript :) Trying to do core javascript.

Comment: You might find [window.onload vs document.onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) useful.

Comment: You can simply call directly
    <body onload="populateTable()">

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body onload="Javascript:populateTable()">  
    <div id="productTable">
    </div>
</body>
```

Stick this into your html pane, the body will run your function on load and get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted to achieve.. onto making it better!